# Download de arquivos em API RESTfull NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Tenho uma API que fiz baseada em um tutorial, onde eu consigo fazer upload de arquivos:

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , multiparty = require('connect-multiparty');

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  var router = express.Router();

  app.use('/api', router);

    /*insira as rotas aqui */
     router.route('/upload')
     .post(multiparty(), require('./controllers/uploads'));

  app.listen(port);

  console.log('conectado a porta ' + port);
```

**Upload.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

    module.exports = function(req, res){
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      var arquivo = req.files.file;
      var temporario = req.files.file.path;

      var novo = './uploads/' + req.files.file.name;
        fs.rename(temporario, novo, function(err){
            if(err){
                res.status(500).json({error: err})
            }
            res.json({message: "enviado com sucesso.", file: novo});
        })
    }
```

Consigo fazer o upload com sucesso, ele salva em uma pasta do projeto da Api, mas e quanto ao download dos uploads q eu faço? Como seria isso? algum exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver fazendo da seguinte forma:

**download.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

module.exports = function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    var file = __dirname + '/../uploads/foto.jpeg';
    res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
}
```

**E em server.js adicionei:**

```
router.route('/download')
     .get(multiparty(), require('./controllers/download'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Se não necessitar de nenhuma validação para acessar os arquivos você pode apenas servir os arquivos estaticamente. Para isso adicione no seu arquivo `Server.js` as seguintes linhas:

```
const path = require('path');

// ...

application.use('/arquivos', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

E assim você poderá acessar o arquivo pela `URL` do seu projeto + `/arquivos` + o nome do arquivo.

> [**Entregando arquivos estáticos no Express**](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/starter/static-files.html)
>
> Para entregar arquivos estáticos como imagens, arquivos CSS, e arquivos JavaScript, use a função de middleware express.static integrada no Express.
>
> Passe o nome do diretório que contém os ativos estáticos para a função de middleware express.static para iniciar a entregar os arquivos diretamente. Por exemplo, use o código a seguir para entregar imagens, arquivos CSS, e arquivos JavaScript em um diretório chamado public:
>
> ```
> app.use(express.static('public'));
> ```
>
> Agora, é possível carregar os arquivos que estão no diretório public:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
> http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
> http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
> http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
> http://localhost:3000/hello.html
> ```